# R: change bar labels in geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

Below is my data:

```
library(ggplot2)  
myData <- data.frame(
  x = c("windows", "macos", "html5"),
  y = c(15, 56, 34)
)


ggplot(myData, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width = 0.5)
```

And my resulted plot:
[image]

I would like to change the bar names to `Windows`, `MacOS`, `HTML5`. How do I configure that with `ggplot`? (Note that I can't change the original data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just give the new `labels` to your `x` variable

```r
library(tidyverse)  

ggplot(myData, aes(x = fct_reorder(x, -y), y = y)) + 
  geom_col(width = 0.5) +
  scale_x_discrete(breaks = c("windows", "macos", "html5"),
                   labels = c("Windows", "MacOS", "HTML5"))

# or 
my_x_labels <- setNames(c("Windows", "MacOS", "HTML5"),
                        c("windows", "macos", "html5"))
ggplot(myData, aes(x = fct_reorder(x, -y), y = y)) + 
  geom_col(width = 0.5) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = my_x_labels) +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

```r
# or
myData <- myData %>% 
  mutate(x = factor(x, 
                    levels = c("windows", "macos", "html5"),
                    labels = c("Windows", "MacOS", "HTML5")))

ggplot(myData, aes(x = fct_reorder(x, -y), y = y)) + 
  geom_col(width = 0.5)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-11-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>